# Ubuntu WireGuard no handshake

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, client, wireguard

I am trying to set up WireGuard VPN. I have set up the interface and the client. but when I run `sudo wg`, despite seeing the interface and peer information, data is only sent and not received, so I have no handshake. What might be the reason for that? I am  a little hesitant as to if I have put a correct endpoint address and allowed IP address.

If someone could help with that it would be great!

```
modinfo wireguard 
filename:       /lib/modules/5.6.7-050607-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireguard/wireguard.ko
alias:          net-pf-16-proto-16-family-wireguard
alias:          rtnl-link-wireguard
version:        1.0.0
author:         Jason A. Donenfeld <Jason@zx2c4.com>
description:    WireGuard secure network tunnel
license:        GPL v2
srcversion:     0DD380162CD80B77F6B9585
depends:        libblake2s,udp_tunnel,curve25519-x86_64,libchacha20poly1305,ip6_udp_tunnel,libcurve25519-generic
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           wireguard
vermagic:       5.6.7-050607-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        41:F9:8A:DC:37:C6:5D:1B:67:7B:1C:17:65:E0:E0:C7:8C:55:35:79
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      01:B9:4C:CD:F0:C9:2C:3B:D2:5D:AF:A4:31:F0:FE:4F:53:7E:A1:F7:
                F7:C6:3C:42:2C:CE:2A:2C:85:A5:9A:53:00:47:FB:5D:A5:48:27:0E:
                B5:5E:8A:BD:DB:D1:04:E6:87:F0:88:E8:2B:74:18:A2:CB:B2:3F:06:
                9C:1C:9B:06:CB:57:60:14:84:7A:AD:1E:76:D8:D5:10:9A:2B:67:32:
                D1:DB:1D:C5:D2:4D:11:A8:98:21:62:A9:26:CE:5A:19:1C:AB:97:34:
                44:2E:38:F0:39:C3:92:30:F3:2B:A7:E8:66:03:33:CF:7A:88:EC:14:
                C4:0B:29:FD:78:4D:99:07:8D:77:09:DA:6B:8E:2D:6E:31:D4:A1:95:
                FB:92:EC:24:87:78:46:6D:4C:BC:9C:CF:2A:65:00:31:21:D7:9D:66:
                FE:48:FC:A8:89:38:72:04:26:0A:17:BB:A1:5E:19:09:48:41:A1:12:
                81:DC:2F:AB:47:62:6C:89:A7:18:8D:3D:2A:F7:28:9B:3C:FB:16:7E:
                DF:EE:23:B3:93:52:D7:21:D7:20:E4:B6:D1:9E:EF:D0:AF:11:F4:80:
                57:EF:8D:0D:03:1D:9B:83:DF:98:81:55:20:8B:59:4F:38:7D:D8:FA:
                78:E2:ED:A5:A2:3B:41:3C:79:FB:E4:D4:2B:88:D9:B4:88:B4:DE:2E:
                B9:13:51:75:BE:D4:73:44:40:CA:F1:1F:36:5F:56:D3:D9:06:CC:E8:
                5A:4A:91:77:BD:04:7E:C9:F9:3F:7A:F7:C6:30:EF:53:60:CD:8D:6C:
                2D:AF:B8:9A:D7:8C:BB:ED:30:6C:5F:AC:3C:E3:5F:15:78:5E:89:6E:
                4A:35:E9:E6:CF:93:CD:56:F0:90:2A:7D:FA:73:02:4D:0A:93:7A:34:
                DD:2C:CC:C6:35:4C:F3:4B:01:5D:F8:88:44:FF:C9:E8:02:68:4C:FD:
                E3:F3:47:7C:8B:74:5E:0E:FD:0E:DB:88:8C:D7:3A:4A:43:43:52:63:
                A3:67:77:8E:AF:3E:9F:8A:79:7E:28:A5:71:38:60:46:AD:08:F7:FD:
                6B:38:27:2E:71:2B:CC:52:96:5A:FB:DF:C6:50:AC:38:E1:4D:55:65:
                AE:23:DD:DF:BF:29:C0:DD:F1:A7:77:23:30:17:24:C9:A3:6D:BA:A2:
                4B:A4:BC:F7:96:A7:8E:2F:F6:13:B8:21:44:56:A0:AB:51:03:3C:9C:
                C2:65:57:2E:02:1B:A6:33:B2:1D:CD:4C:12:46:A2:D7:61:7C:43:5B:
                58:3F:89:87:E1:DA:E7:5A:FD:F6:D6:89:9F:FD:E6:8A:63:2D:75:B6:
                E6:D0:D4:08:E9:14:03:B2:50:9E:60:2E
```

```
nvidia, 435.21, 5.4.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 435.21, 5.4.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
wireguard, 1.0.20200413, 5.4.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
wireguard, 1.0.20200413, 5.5.4-050504-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 30
       serial: a8:6d:aa:e4:81:44
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-26-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 ip=192.168.1.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:b431c000-b431ffff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing the `wireguard` VPN software, it installs a `wireguard` dkms kernel module. This was fine prior to Ubuntu 20.04. Since 20.04, this kernel driver is already included, so `dkms status` shows us this error...

```
nvidia, 435.21, 5.4.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
wireguard, 1.0.20200413, 5.4.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
wireguard, 1.0.20200413, 5.5.4-050504-generic, x86_64: installed
```

The fix is to remove the wireguard dkms kernel driver when using 20.04...

`sudo dkms remove wireguard/1.0.20200413 --all` # remove driver from all kernels

`dkms status` should now show...

```
nvidia, 435.21, 5.4.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Then `reboot` and retest your VPN connection.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107232/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-ubuntu-wireguard-no-handshake).